# Why does my site zoom in/out when a put a "www" in front?

Tags: web

My first website is well under way, but it zooms out (or in, depending on the broser) when I put a "www" before the domain, what could cause that? I really only have the site to show at this point, but will answer questions as needed. I'm using Django and apache2 with mod_wsgi and psycopg2.

[postacle.com](http://postacle.com)

[www.postacle.com](http://www.postacle.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't for me. Chances are your browser has a zoom setting that you accidentally changed for your site, but it only applies to a single domain. Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to reset the zoom setting (that's Control plus Zero).

Comment: Ok, so that fixed th problem in Opera... not for google and chrome, though I tried extensively...

Comment: ok, you're totally right, the command is just ctrl+0 in firefox and ctr+= in opera. Going to try chrome some more, but will accept your answer shortly! Thanks!